# How to send .ipa file to client for testing

Tags: ipa

I'm sorry for this simple question. I want to send .ipa file to client for testing. How can I do this without using any sites...

Comment: You can use itunes' testflight if you don't want to use any other site.

Comment: you can just send an e-mail with the ipa and profile...

Comment: Copy it to a floppy disk and mail it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best and easy way for share application with client, either you can use `apple testflight` using `itunes connect` or you can just make `.ipa` and upload your `.ipa` on this link https://www.diawi.com/

Comment: Does this really still work? This looks like it won't: "Allow your testers to find the app on Diawi's mobile web app using their UDID (iOS only)." Apps no longer have access to the UDID.

Comment: it takes 1 day for review is there a faster way such as sending the .apk file on android?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by following this guide for Exporting Your App ipa file for Testing purposes.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html

Note: Although the recommended way is beta testing via [TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/). It's beneficial for the long term. Also, it has easy OTA installation.

Comment: can u please explain "Also, it has easy OTA installation" @Nishant

Answer (score 2):

You can use Fabric Mac Application.
https://get.fabric.io/ios?locale=en-us